# Stripping output of grep using regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a bash script I'm trying to tweak to output the contents of grep a certain way.  Here's what my script looks like right now:

```
files=/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/*

for f in $files
  do
    echo "${f##*/}" && sudo cat $f/metadata.json | grep \"version\"
  done
```

output looks like this right now:

```
elasticsearch
  "version": "0.3.10"
```

I'd like to just have it output the actual number without the "version": in front or the quotes.  The above example I'd like to look like this.

```
elasticsearch
  0.3.10
```

I'm new to regular expressions so I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be.  Would it be useful to pipe the output from grep to use the sed utility with regex search?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "${f##*/}" && sudo cat $f/metadata.json | sed -n '/"version": "\([^"]*\)"/ s//\1/p'
```

filter and reformat directly in sed

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `echo` command inside for loop by this:

```
echo "${f##*/}" && sudo awk -F ': *' '{gsub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}' $f/metadata.json
```

Comment: You can also get rid of the `sudo cat file |` and do `sudo awk '...' file`

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech I updated it. Actually even `"${f##*/}"` can be handled in awk :)